# Replace UITextField Placeholder

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, storyboard, placeholder

I have a 'IBOutlet UITextField* textField' connect with a UITextField in a .xib file. 
I use this element as a combobox in a viewcontroller class which is connect to a VC in the storyboard.
My question is how can i modify the placeholder text? I already try the 3 following methods, but nothing work!!

```
-(void) setPlaceholder:(NSString *)label
{
    textField.placeholder = label;
    [textField setPlaceholder:label];
    [textField cell ]setPlaceholderString:label];
}
```

thx for your answers

Comment: some where else you went wrong otherwise it'l work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it in the viewdidload method of your viewcontroller method because the placeholder field wasn't initialize when i called my setPlaceholder method

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're textField has been synthesised, you should be able to use: 
    `textField.placeholder = label`

Answer (score 0):

`textField.placeholder = @"placeholder"` shall work, check if `label` and `textField` actually point to respective objects.

Comment: it works, but i put textField.placeholder = @"placeholder" in the viewdidload method because the placeholder field wasn't initialize when i called my setPlaceholder method